# Search through a multi dimensional array with 1 foreach?

Tags: php

I want to minimize a nested foreach loop within my function. But the problem is, that I am using a 2D Array which is as followed:

```
    $Multi_Array = array (
        'Users' => array ('User1', 'User2'),
        'Passwords' => array ('Pass1', 'Pass2'),
        'Warnings' => array (1, 30),
        'Admin' => array ('True', 'False')      
    );
```

I currently have two foreach loops to work with my array. How would I minimize the nested foreach loop and use just 1?

Comment: what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: This is just from an admin perspective. I'm experimenting with a tool, pulling all the data out of a database, putting them into their own perspective arrays; Joining up the keys with each value, so key 0 for `users` will be linked to key 0 for the other array keys.    but i want to minimize nested foreach loops,

Comment: @user2146021: You didn't answer his question. What are you trying to do with this array that doesn't work for you? Sort it? How? What doesn't work?

Comment: What is purpose of it? Speed? Using less memory? Less code? And what functional you want get finally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i can think of is to make the foreach statement in a function, then have it check if it is an array using is_array(), and on true, it would then pass the array to the function.

```
function check_array($array){
foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
 if(is_array($value)){
  check_array($value);}
 else { ...do something with $value...}
}
```

Comment: So your saying use a form of recursion? put the array through the same function?

Comment: Yeah updated original post with sample of code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but how about something like this:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($Multi_Array['Users']);$i++)
{
    $users[$Multi_Array['Users'][$i]]['Password'] = $Multi_Array['Passwords'][$i];
    $users[$Multi_Array['Users'][$i]]['Warning'] = $Multi_Array['Warnings'][$i];
    $users[$Multi_Array['Users'][$i]]['Admin'] = $Multi_Array['Admin'][$i];
}
```

It's not foreach, but it's 1 loop.